# How to change color only one tab GtkNotebook

Tags: css, gtk3

I'm working on **Ubuntu 14 with GTK version 3.10.8**. I wouldn't like to upgrade to Ubuntu 16 now…….

Nevertheless, I have a question of understanding with **CSS** and **GtkNoteBook**

My test

Is it possible to change color of tab for one tab only, like

```
GtkNotebook tab:nth-child(3) {} or
GtkNotebook tab:nth-child(4){} or
GtkNotebook tab:nth-child(5) etc …..
```

I Found it's ok or not for

/* first ok */
/* last ok  */

/* odd ok  */

/* even ok  */

/* 1 ok  */

/* 2n+1 ok  */

/* 3n+4 non ok  */

/* 2 non ok  */

/* one non ok  */

/* one non ok  */

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: ISO-8859-1 -*-
# notebook_20.py
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

def _destroy_cb(widget, data=None):
    Gtk.main_quit()

window = Gtk.Window()
window.connect("destroy", _destroy_cb)

screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()

css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()

css = """
        /* Theme any label within a notebook */
        GtkNotebook tab GtkLabel {background-color: green;color: cyan;}
        GtkNotebook > GtkLabel {background-color: pink;color: cyan;}


        GtkNotebook {              /*------  OR use " GtkNotebook#notebook OR GtkNotebook.mynotebook  */ 
        -GtkWidget-focus-line-width: 0;    /* Remove focus line (dotted line) around text on all tabs */
        -GtkNotebook-tab-overlap: 0; 
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
        border-radius: 15px; 
        border-width: 4px;               
        }   


        GtkLabel.first_label {        /* another way to select tab label */
        color: green;                 /* overides last font color selection  */
        font: Serif italic 10;        /* overides last font & font size selection */
        }

        /* first ok */
        /* last ok  */
        /* odd ok  */
        /* even ok  */
        /* 1 ok  */
        /* 2n+1 ok  */
        /* 3n+4 non ok  */
        /* 2 non ok  */
        /* one non ok  */
        /* one non ok  */

        GtkNotebook tab:nth-child(3n+4) {  /* modification 1er onglet tab "FirstTab */
        background-color: pink;             /* tab background color */
        color: green;                         /* tab font color */
        font: Sans 12;                      /* tab font & font size */
        }
        """
css_provider.load_from_data(css)


context = Gtk.StyleContext()
context.add_provider_for_screen(screen, css_provider,
                                Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER)

box = Gtk.VBox()
window.add(box)

notebook = Gtk.Notebook()
box.pack_start(notebook, False, False, 0)

for i in range(10):
    bufferf = "Prepend Frame %d" % (i+1)
    bufferl = "Page %d" % (i+1)

    frame = Gtk.Frame()
    frame.set_border_width(10)
    frame.set_size_request(100, 75)
    label = Gtk.Label(bufferf)
    frame.add(label)
    label.show()

    label2 = Gtk.Label(bufferl)
    notebook.append_page(frame, label2)
    frame.show()

window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Could you help me
perhap must I change gtk version (now I have version 3.10.8 )
Thank you  by advance

Comment: are you saying in your tests that you successfully changed the colour or one tab?

Comment: The tab:nth-child() trick works for me, but I don't understand the arguments. For example, the third tab I have to target via ... (4). Which confuses me. If it starts at 1, then it should be 3, right? And if it starts at 0, it should be 2. But strangely enough I have to use 4 for the third tab ... I am confused. To haxxxton: yes, this works as-is, also via .set_name().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok thank you very much for your help. My understanding is :
- GtkNotebook tab:nth-child(3) {} is "implemented" in CSS3 specification, but
- not implemented in Gtk 3 at  version 3.10.8.

In fact I changed my approch. 
first I would like manage a notebook.
second when I changing date in tab child I would like indicate status modified
if data no changed status is no modified
After one or two night!!!, I found my need is to manage only two state.

my solution like is :

```
if status == 'modified';
    label.set_name ('modified)
else
    label.set_name ('no_modified)
.......

GtkNotebook > #no_modified {background-color: green;}
GtkNotebook > #modified {background-color: red;}
```

or something like that.
I'm testing this next day.
Thank you very much so one

Answer (score 0):

You could add a special CSS ID within the CSS string:

```
    #page2 {
        background-color: #0f0;
    }
```

Then set_name for "page 2" with page2.  For example within in the for loop that creates the individual pages:

```
for i in range(10):
    ...
    label2 = Gtk.Label(bufferl)
    if i == 2:
        label2.set_name('page2')
    notebook.append_page(frame, label2)
    frame.show()
```